# Major Speedup Question for a for loop in Pandas/Numpy on a bitwise_xor accumulate

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, bitwise-operators

Ok i am using a for loop as show below to convert this data from to the one below
using xor accumulate. For the entries i have (830401) rows and this is very very slow. is there
any way to speed up this kind of accumulate in pandas or using numpy and then assiging
it back the numpy array itself

```
In [122]: acctable[0:20]
Out[122]: 
    what  dx1  dx2  dx3  dx4  dx5  dx6  dx7  dx8  dx9
0      4    2   10    8    0    5    7    1   13   11
1      4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
2      6    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
3     14    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
4     12    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    8    0
5      4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
6      1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0

...      ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...
830477    15    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
830478     3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
830479    11    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
830480     9    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
830481    11    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0

[830482 rows x 10 columns]
```

Here is what i tried and it literally can take a full minute and i have larger data sets to work with
so any shortcuts or best methods would trull be helpful:

```
# Update: Instead of all 800k of 'what', i put the first 5 numbers in rstr so you can see how i'm xor accumulating. You should be able to copy/paste the first 6 elements of the data from with pd.read_clipboard() and assign to acctable. 

In [121]: rstr
Out[121]: array([ 4,  4, 12, 14,  6,  4], dtype=int8)
  
dt = np.int8
rstr = np.array(acctable.loc[:5, ('what')], dtype=dt)
for x in range(4): # # Prime Sequencing Functions
   wuttr = np.bitwise_xor.accumulate(np.r_[[rstr[-(x+1)]], acctable.loc[x, 'what':]], dtype=dt)
   acctable.loc[x+1, "what":] = wuttr[:end]
```

After:

```
In [122]: acctable[0:20]
Out[122]: 
    what  dx1  dx2  dx3  dx4  dx5  dx6  dx7  dx8  dx9
0      4    2   10    8    0    5    7    1   13   11
1      4    0    2    8    0    0    5    2    3   14
2      6    2    2    0    8    8    8   13   15   12
3     14    8   10    8    8    0    8    0   13    2
4     12    2   10    0    8    0    0    8    8    5
5      4    8   10    0    0    8    8    8    0    8
6      1    5   13    7    7    7   15    7   15   15
...      ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...
830477    15   15    7    0    0    5    9   14   10    3
830478     3   12    3    4    4    4    1    8    6   12
830479    11    8    4    7    3    7    3    2   10   12
830480     9    2   10   14    9   10   13   14   12    6
830481    11    2    0   10    4   13    7   10    4    8

[830482 rows x 10 columns]
```

It's a simple accumulate but you need to have the previous row to continue the accumulation and the only way i could of is using the for loop. Also "rstr" variable is actually the "what" column.

Thanks!

I received this result from an ai but it only works on the first rows:

```
what_arr = acctable['what'].to_numpy().reshape(-1)  # Reshape to ensure 1D array

# Modified XOR accumulation:
all_what_arr = np.concatenate([[what_arr[0]], what_arr[1:]])
cumulative_xor = np.bitwise_xor.accumulate(all_what_arr)
shifted_xor = cumulative_xor[1:].reshape(-1, 1)
acctable.iloc[1:, 1:] = shifted_xor ^ acctable.iloc[1:, 1:]


In [171]: acctable
Out[171]: 
        what  dx1  dx2  dx3  dx4  dx5  dx6  dx7  dx8  dx9
0          4    2   10    8    0    5    7    1   13   11
1          6    0    2    8    0    0    5    2    3   14
2         14    4    6    6   12   14   12   11   11   10
3         12    2   10    0   10   10    8    8   15    8
4          4   12   14    4    4   14    4   12    4   11
```

Here are the timeit values as you can see Andrej's modification and njit use were a huge factor of speedup!

```
In [262]:  import timeit
     ...: 
     ...:  setup = """
     ...:  import numpy as np
     ...:  import pandas as pd
     ...:  from numba import njit
     ...:  
     ...:  
     ...:  def do_work_no_njit(df):
     ...:      dt = np.int8
     ...:      end = -1
     ...:      rstr = np.array(df.loc[:, 0], dtype=dt)
     ...:      for x in range(len(df)):
     ...:          wuttr = np.bitwise_xor.accumulate(np.r_[[rstr[-(x+1)]], df.loc[x, 0:]], dtype=dt)
     ...:          df.loc[x+1, 0:] = wuttr[:end]
     ...:  
     ...:  @njit
     ...:  def do_work(vals):
     ...:      for row in range(vals.shape[0] - 1):
     ...:          for i in range(vals.shape[1] - 1):
     ...:              vals[row + 1, i + 1] = vals[row, i] ^ vals[row + 1, i]
     ...:  
     ...:  # Replace with your DataFrame creation code
     ...:  df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 15, size=(1000000, 10)), dtype=np.int8) # Example DataFrame, dtype=np.int8) # Example DataFrame
     ...:  """
     ...: 
     ...:  stmt = """
     ...:  do_work(df.values)
     ...:  """
     ...: 
     ...:  stmtnonjit = """
     ...:  do_work_no_njit(df.copy())
     ...:  """
     ...: 
     ...:  number = 1  # Adjust the number of repetitions as needed
     ...: 
     ...:  time = timeit.timeit(stmtnonjit, setup, number=number)
     ...:  print(f"Average time per execution no njit: {time / number:.4f} seconds")
     ...: 
     ...:  time = timeit.timeit(stmt, setup, number=number)
     ...:  print(f"Average time per execution with njit and optimized code by Andrej: {time / number:.4f} seconds")
     ...: 
Average time per execution no njit: 73.3801 seconds
Average time per execution with njit and optimized code by Andrej: 0.0442 seconds
```

Comment: I am unable to get your sample code running unfortunately, can you edit the question to have a running code sample?

Comment: I fixed the code. this should help, let me know

Comment: What value is `end` supposed to have?

Comment: so basically what we do is accumulate the second what with the first row, so what[1] ^ what[[0] is assigned to dx1[1].  then dx1[1] ^ dx1[0] is assigned to dx2[1], etc, etc.   4^4 = 0, then 0 xor 2 is 2.  So basically the after column is the ending xor accumulation. let me know if that explains it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [numba](/questions/tagged/numba) to speed up the computation:

```py
from numba import njit


@njit
def do_work(vals):
    for row in range(vals.shape[0] - 1):
        for i in range(vals.shape[1] - 1):
            vals[row + 1, i + 1] = vals[row, i] ^ vals[row + 1, i]


do_work(df.values)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   what  dx1  dx2  dx3  dx4  dx5  dx6  dx7  dx8  dx9
0     4    2   10    8    0    5    7    1   13   11
1     4    0    2    8    0    0    5    2    3   14
2     6    2    2    0    8    8    8   13   15   12
3    14    8   10    8    8    0    8    0   13    2
4    12    2   10    0    8    0    0    8    8    5
```

---

Initial `df`:

```
   what  dx1  dx2  dx3  dx4  dx5  dx6  dx7  dx8  dx9
0     4    2   10    8    0    5    7    1   13   11
1     4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
2     6    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
3    14    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
4    12    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: That is very fast Andrei . do you think you can modify this to work, it works with the first two rows: what_arr = acctable['what'].to_numpy().reshape(-1)  # Reshape to ensure 1D array

# Modified XOR accumulation:
all_what_arr = np.concatenate([[what_arr[0]], what_arr[1:]])
cumulative_xor = np.bitwise_xor.accumulate(all_what_arr)
shifted_xor = cumulative_xor[1:].reshape(-1, 1)
acctable.iloc[1:, 1:] = shifted_xor ^ acctable.iloc[1:, 1:]

Comment: @oppressionslayer Please edit your question and put the code there - the comments don't support multiline formatting.

Comment: I updated my answer with the output from bard's answer to my question, if you want me to open up a second question i can, the initial result seems promising. Thanks btw Andrej! that was very very fast with numba

Comment: i haven't timed it, but the answer came back instantaneously with numba where i was waiting 20 seconds before

Comment: @oppressionslayer I'm not sure if you can do it with simple numpy methods here - because you have dependent variables (every row is dependent on previous row etc.) With numba, that's easy (it's just one simple XOR operation, which I think is one of fastest things computers can do. And you don't do any memory allocation).

Comment: Sounds good Andrej, i didn't realize numba was that fast at optimization

Comment: @oppressionslayer Yes, numba compiles this `do_work()` function to optimized machine code, so the speed is comparable to C code (in general)